# How to create a MP4 video from scratch?

Tags: go, gif, mp4

I'm trying to write a service with Go that converts GIF to MP4.

For GIF there's a builtin package "image/gif" which contains tools for decoding a GIF.

But no such package exists for MP4.

So I'm considering creating the MP4 file myself.

After decoding a GIF, I have access to its images and parameters like delay, so if I figure out something like a "template for MP4 file", I can use these information to create one, right?

Comment: Have a look at some binding to libav and work with it. one such example, I can't attest to its quality: https://github.com/nareix/codec

Comment: `os.Cmd` and shelling out to ffmpeg may also be another option.

Comment: So how long would it take for one to implement MP4 encoding/decoding from scratch?

Comment: a couple of years to learn the algorithms and theory, and then a few months to implement probably :)

Comment: No wonder almost every "modern" programming languages rely on the C-binding solution or command-line solution when it comes to MP4 processing.

Answer (score 2):

Mp4 is not the one universal standard of video data. It's dozens of standards called MPEG-4 now. But if you mean .Mp4 most times you mean H.264 in some container.
Proper implementation of H.264 (that will work as fast and as stable that ready-made solutions) is very hard work that requires advanced computer science skills, expert programming skills, expert knowledge of the H.264-related standards, and a lot of time. The draft that you can find on ITU site contains 671 pages and it's referenced to few (or dozens?) other standards.
And another bad news: draft of standard is not the current standard. You need to buy it.
Some of aspects of realization of H.264: frame data compression, entropy coding, code correction, video filters, color profiles. It's really complicated things, all of them.

So why not have try to use the ffmpeg?
You can execute ffmpeg executable with "os/exec" package:

```
out, err := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-f", "gif", "-i", gifFileName, mp4FileName).Output()
```

Or even try use ffmpeg bindings for go https://github.com/giorgisio/goav

The use of ready-made solutions will save years of your work ;)